# Return the result of a record pair with same identifier and one field with/without null value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have these data records:

```
ImageId     ParentId
image1      Null      // wanna have
image1      1         // wanna have
image3      2        
image2      1
```

How should my query be written that I get the records with same ImageId AND the other row of the Pair result having always ParentId value Null?

Comment: You need to explain further here. Why not return the 3rd **row** (they aren't called "records") too?

Comment: Fixed it. 3rd row can NOT be image1 as it occurs always in a Pair.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the ImageID where there is a row with ParentID null and a row with ParentId = 1 here are 2 queries that you can use.

> ```
> select a.ImageId
> from table_name a
> join table_name b on a.ImageId = b.ImageId
> where a.ParentID is null
> and b.ParentID = 1;
> ```
>
> ```
> | ImageId |
> | :------ |
> | image1  |
> ```

> ```
> select ImageId
> from table_name
> where ParentID is null or ParentID = 1
> group by ImageId
> having count(distinct coalesce(ParentID,999)) = 2;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | ImageId |
> | :------ |
> | image1  |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=13f58062bbe9886b0621561af207a24b)*

Comment: The ParentId is of course not hardcoded ;-)

Answer (score 0):

We can try to use `CTE` to find  `ParentId IS NULL` ImageId and then use that to judgment  by `EXISTS`

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM T
    WHERE ParentId IS NULL
)
SELECT ImageId,ParentId
FROM (
  SELECT *,
         COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY ParentId) cnt
  FROM T 
) t1 
WHERE cnt > 1 AND 
EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM CTE c WHERE c.ImageId = t1.ImageId)
UNION ALL
SELECT ImageId,ParentId
FROM CTE
```

or we can use `count` window function with your logic to make it simple.

```
SELECT ImageId,ParentId
FROM (
  SELECT *,
         COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY ParentId) cnt
  FROM T 
) t1 
WHERE (cnt > 1 AND 
  EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM T tt 
    WHERE tt.ImageId = t1.ImageId 
    AND tt.ParentId IS NULL
  )
)
OR ParentId IS NULL
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=dadc69f45d434cbf1bdfda76db7d105f)

**EDIT**

I saw you edit your question, we can just use `COUNT` window function to get duplicate rows by `PARTITION BY` your identifier columns

```
SELECT ImageId,ParentId
FROM (
  SELECT *,
         COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY ImageId) cnt
  FROM T 
) t1
WHERE cnt > 1
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=1d287d5ab47c0feea9acc4c2bd688aa3)

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to do is to find the images having one or more null values and one of more not null values we can use the fact that `COUNT()` does not include null values.

- 'count(ParentID) > 0` checks that there is at least one not null value of ParentID
- count(coalesce(ParentID,1)) <> count(ParentID) checks that there is at least one null value of ParentID, which will be counted in the first expression because it will have been changed to 1 by coalesce.
  We use string_agg to show the parentID's present for the image.

> ```
> select 
>   ImageId,
>   String_agg(ParentID,',') "ParentID's"
> from table_name
> group by ImageID
> having count(ParentID) > 0
> and count(coalesce(ParentID,1)) <> count(ParentID)
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ImageId | ParentID's
> :------ | :---------
> image1  | 1,2       
> image3  | 2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9e875f9990c02b555deaebc57721e3b2)*